# How to make my app accept search intents from other apps?

Tags: android, search, android-intent

My searchable activity currently looks like this in the Android Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.Search"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

</activity>
```

I would like to be able to add my application to the preinstalled "Google Search"-app as a searchable element and therefore accept its search intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html) on the android dev blog. What I've been missing was the xml attribute `android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"` in my `searchable.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct. Did you enable your app in the Google-Search app settings, to be searchable?

Comment: It's not listed. I forgot to mention that Android Lint adds a warning to the activity node saying "Exported activity does not require permission".